AnalysisException: mismatched input ';' expecting <EOF>
Trying to load data into Iceberg with pysaprk (version 3.5.1)
%%sparksql

ALTER TABLE
    scheme.table
SET IDENTIFIER FIELDS a, b, c;

ALTER TABLE
    scheme.table
WRITE DISTRIBUTED BY PARTITION LOCALLY ORDERED BY d, e ASC NULLS LAST;

And get this error
AnalysisException:
mismatched input ';' expecting {<EOF>, ',', '.'}
== SQL ==

I tried different combinations of ';', nothing worked.

I found the answer - SparkSQL doesn’t support executing multiple queries with a single call to spark.sql

It seems, Your First Query is wrong. So while parsing the query, parser is expecting one of following {<EOF>, ',', '.'}. If you will correct first query you should be able to execute two queries delimited by ;
Not sure exactly what you are trying to achieve. But I Believe SET IDENTIFIER is not supported in Spark SQL.

I realize there is something wrong with the query, but what is it? Here is a link to Iceberg documentation for DDL with Spark.

I tried running them separately in Jupyter Notebook and they work fine without the ';', but in my case I need one script containing two ALTER TABLE queries.

Can you try changing/adding/removing magic command. Change '%%sparksql'  to '%%sql' . Or compare it with the working one.

That's not the problem, I found the answer
